# Azure VHD decryption on localhost

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, azure-disk

can I use Key Vault to encrypt OS/Data disk attached to Linux VM and later get encryption passphrase to unlock VHD after download on local machine?

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This step disables encryption of the OS or the data volume or both on
>   the running Windows IaaS VM. However, as mentioned in the previous
>   section, disabling OS disk encryption for Linux isn't supported. The
>   decryption step is allowed only for data drives on Linux VMs as long
>   as the OS disk isn't encrypted.

It seems it does not support decryption of Linux OS disk, and only support for the data disk. For details about decryption, see [Decryption workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-overview#decryption-workflow).